# Как задать разный размер для нажатой и не нажатой кнопки?

Tags: android, button, style

Я использую shape для нажатой и не нажатой кнопки.
В них указан разный сайз.
Формирую из них стиль и применяю его к моей кнопке но ей надо обязательно указать layout_width и layout_height, а размер из shape она не подхватывает.

Comment: реально изменить размер можно только, например, программно, с помощью onTouchListenner (изменяя margin, например). При помощи стиля, насколько я знаю, нельзя.

Comment: Понял спасибо. Попробую, пока, реализовать так. Может кто-то еще, что-то сообразит.

Comment: попробуйте ScaleAnimation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете задать `width` и `height` для большого размера кнопки, а маленький размер компенсировать через `inset` для шейпа.
 Фактически кнопка будет иметь один и тот же размер, но за счет инсетов в одном из состояний кнопка будет выглядеть меньше.

Создаем маленькую кнопку для не нажатого состояния - кнопка будет уменьшена на `2dp` с каждой стороны.

**res/drawable/small_button.xml:**

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="2dp" android:insetLeft="2dp"
    android:insetRight="2dp" android:insetTop="2dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#7fce69"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dip"/>
    <padding android:left="8dp" android:top="8dp"
             android:right="8dp" android:bottom="8dp" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

Создаем обычную для нажатого.

**res/drawable/big_button.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#7fce69"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dip" />
    <padding android:left="8dp" android:top="8dp"
             android:right="8dp" android:bottom="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

Создаем селектор.

**res/drawable/scale_backgound.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/big_button" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/small_button"></item>

</selector>
```

Назначаем наш селектор кнопке:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Scale Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/scale_backgound" />
```