# Scale для view элемента

Tags: android, android-layout

Как при увеличении *view*-элемента (*Scale Animation*) сделать так, чтобы он (*view*-элемент) был сверху (замещал) другие соседние элементы?

Где это делается — в *activity* или в *layout*?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446438/177345 ?

Answer (score 1):

В layout. Используйте FrameLayout, по средствам gravity да и padding-гов в нём можно неплохо позиционировать вьюхи, а вьюху, которую вы хотите увеличить, добавьте последней.

Comment: У меня есть более 70 вьюх (ІmageButton) на GridLayout , эффект увеличение нужен для того чтобы пользователь был уверен что он сделал правильный выбор, ваше решение мне не подходит. Может еще есть идеи?

Comment: да, есть, используйте CardView!